# Health Check: Failed on AWS Lightsail load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, aws-application-load-balancer

The health check of my load balancer's instances is failing for no reason.

[image: Lightsail load balancer health check screenshot]

The health check URL of one of those instance is : http://3.72.123.226/health.html and send back the HTML page successfully

So why the health check is failing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you created the instance from a brand new Lightsail blueprint for Magento, its default behavior redirects to the homepage. It fails since the ALB is looking for `200 OK` status in the health check.

To remediate this perform the following:

1. Log in to Magento admin page at: `http://{your instance}/admin`
2. In the left navigation go to `Stores -> Configuration -> Web` and open the **Url Options** section
3. Select **No** for `Auto-redirect to Base URL` option and click on `Save Config`
4. Go to `System -> Cache Management` and click on **Flush Magento Cache** for this to take place

After 30 seconds or so health check status should switch to **Passed**